# Quickbase Pipelines: How to extract nested JSON array, using Jinja, into Multi-Select Text field?

Tags: python, json, jinja2, quickbase

I am using [Quickbase](https://www.quickbase.com/) [Pipelines](https://helpv2.quickbase.com/hc/en-us/articles/4570257915924-About-Quickbase-Pipelines-) to pull data from a REST API and save it into a table. The flow of the pipeline is:

```
B. Fetch JSON
C. Prepare Bulk Record Upsert
D. Iterate over JSON records
For each JSON Handler - JSON Objects (D) Do
    E. Add Bulk Upsert Row
F. Commit Upsert
```

In the *"Add a Bulk Upsert Row"* step I am mapping fields from my table to properties of incoming JSON records.

I am facing a challenge around "custom fields" in my JSON records. There are fields where instead of simply appearing as `"key": "value"` pairs in JSON, they appear in a nested array similar to this:

```
"custom_fields": [
    {
        "key": "street",
        "value": "foo",
    },
    {
        "key": "city",
        "value": "bar",
    },
    {
        "key": "state",
        "value": "baz",
    }
]
```

I've been able to extract specific values by their key from this structure using this Jinja code block inside my upsert step:

```
{% for field in d.custom_fields %}
{% if field['key'] == 'street' %}
    {{ field['value'] }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This works well for *Text*-type fields but this technique fails when trying to get a JSON array value into a *Multi-Select Text*-type field.

When I use the a Jinja code block like the one above to parse this bit of JSON:

```
"custom_fields": [
    {
        "key": "choices",
        "value": [
            "foo",
            "bar",
            "baz"
        ],
    }
]
```

I get these 3 values in my Multi-Select Text field: `[u'foo'`, `u'bar'` and `u'baz']`.

It's as if Quickbase / Jinja are parsing the value from JSON as a literal string rather than an array.

My question is - **How can I get the above JSON value to be transformed into the correct choices: `foo`, `bar` and `baz`?**

---

**Update:** Having examined the activity logs for the pipeline, I've found that the *JSON Object* that QB derived from the actual JSON has the value as `"[u'foo', u'bar', u'baz']"` - a string - which explains the odd values ending up in the table field. Might this be a bug?

I've also found that the same *JSON Object* has a copy of itself under the property `raw_record` and in that copy the value is a sensible `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`. I've not been able, however, to make use of the `raw_record` in my Jinja templates.

Comment: What action are you using to query/get the data that you are then trying to transform... an action from the Records section of the Quickbase channel or are you making a call to the Rest API (Make Request action from Quickbase channel or Webhook channel)?

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question to reflect that I'm using the *Fetch JSON* action in Pipelines.

Comment: Replicating this now...one more Q: Is your Fetch JSON pulling data from QB or some other source?

Comment: Many thanks. Third party REST API.

Answer (score 0):

In your a value for a Multi-Select field in an Add Bulk Upsert Row step you need to transform the array to a comma separated string (similar pattern to what you are using for a logic check on the key 'street'):

```
{% for item in array %}
{{item}}
{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{#Adds a comma between each value from array except the last one #}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you but this technique does not yield the correct results. It returns an array with these values: `[;u;';f;o;o;';;;;u;';b;a;r;';;;;u;';b;a;z;';]`. I think the root cause is that `{{ field['value'] }}` in my example (`array` in yours) is a string representation of the array and not the array itself. Possibly a bug in Quickbase Pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround based on my understanding that Quickbase Pipelines makes the JSON array available to the Jinja template as a string representation of a Python array rather than as the actual Python array.

In my example above, the value of `field['value']` is `"[u'foo', u'bar', u'baz']"`.

The workaround looks like this:

```
{% for field in d.custom_fields %}
{% if field['key'] == 'street' %}
    {{ field['value'] 
       | replace("[", "")
       | replace("]", "") 
       | replace("u'", "")
       | replace("'", "") }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The result of this template is `"foo, bar, baz"` which the "Add Bulk Upsert Row" step correctly enters into my *Multi-Choice Text*-type field.